# How do I display a non-power-of-2-texture as sprite in OpenGL (ES) with no stretching?

Tags: opengl-es, sprite

I want to draw an arbitrary size sprite as a png, say something TOTALLY CRAZY like 56 wide x 30 high.  Not a power of 2 in either dimension.  Also I may want to draw another different sprite that's 72 wide x 33 high.  Indicating this because no 'tricks' are acceptable here, I need to handle general case.

So I have this png (with transparency) and I want to draw it as a sprite with absolutely no stretching, interpolation, etc.  I want it to map 1:1 with pixels on the screen.  Pretend these sprites are pixel art (they may or may not be but they are drawn for the exact resolution).

I understand sprite drawing - 2 triangles as a quad, rendering my texture to that via texture coordinate mapping - however I only understand it for powers of 2.  And I also do not understand how to size my 'quad' and set up my GL matricies such that I can make the sprite be the exact same size in pixels as my sprite

I'm using OpenGL ES so using the new extensions to use non-power-of-2 textures is not acceptable.

I'm only drawing 3-10 sprites at a time so I'm open to suggestions about efficiency but I'm most interested in 'accurate' looking results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a pixel-perfect coordinate system, you could set up your matrices as follows:

```
glViewport(0, window_width, 0, window_height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, window_width, 0, window_height, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

This ensures a 1:1 mapping of OpenGL coordinates to pixels, and puts your origin in the bottom left corner.

As to your texture, if you don't want to rely on the non-power-of-two extension, you *must* pad it to be a power of two. Even though the OpenGL ES spec doesn't say it has to be square as well (as far as I know), I've seen strange things happen on Android with texture sizes like 512 x 128, so it might be best to stick to *square* power-of-two textures.

The thing to note is that texture coordinates in OpenGL are always between 0 and 1, no matter what the pixel size of your texture is. So if your sprite is 48 pixels wide, and you padded it to a texture of 64 x 64, then it will span the x coordinates from 0 to 0.75:

```
1 +--------+
  |        |
  |        |
  +-----+  |
  |\_O_/|  |
  |  O  |  |
  | / \ |  |
0 +-----+--+
  0   0.75 1   <- texture coordinates
  0     48 64  <- pixels
```

So you have to set up these texture coordinates for the corners of your quad. Because we have a pixel-perfect projection, the quad must also be exactly 48 pixels wide.

In conclusion, to draw your sprite at position `x, y` (in pixels from the bottom left), do something like this:

```
float texcoord_x = (float)sprite_width / texture_width;
float texcoord_y = (float)sprite_height / texture_height;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
// bottom left
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2i(x, y);
// bottom right
glTexCoord2f(texcoord_x, 0);
glVertex2i(x + sprite_width, y);
// top right
glTexCoord2f(texcoord_x, texcoord_y);
glVertex2i(x + sprite_width, y + sprite_height);
// top left
glTexCoord2f(0, texcoord_y);
glVertex2i(x, y + sprite_height);
glEnd();
```

I know OpenGL ES doesn't have `glVertex2i` and so on, so you'll have to put these coordinates into a buffer. And it doesn't allow quads, so you'll have to split it up into triangles. But this is the basic idea.

Comment: Looks good - what should I do about the texture interpolation hints?  So that it never tries to 'get smart' and distorts my texture?  Or will they simply not come in to play because the texcoord will match up perfectly with a reference point on the texture (or close enough that the interpolation algorithm will result in the perfect value of my pixel)

Comment: Theoretically, yes. In practice, use GL_NEAREST for both the GL_MIN_FILTER and GL_MAX_FILTER, just to be sure -- and it might even be a bit faster.

Comment: For viewport don't I actually want 0, width - 1, 0, height - 1? And for ortho I'm computing my matrix by hand (since ES2 doesnt include glOrtho) and as of now I'm using 640/2 and 960/2 in that calc (width and height vals) -- should I have -1 there? .... I have your technique very nearly working but I'm encountering aliasing and something is wrong.... (may be this, may be my image loading and handling, still unsure so appreciate your input as I debug!)

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure it should go from 0 to `width` and `height`. `glViewport` expects the width and height of the viewport, not the right and top. From 640/2 and 960/2, I gather you want your origin in the centre of the screen? It might be easier not to do that, but to put a translation into the modelview matrix instead. Open a new question if you can't figure it out, and add a comment here to point me towards it :)

Comment: I definitely am lost :)  And I gave some sligtly wrong info about the matrix I'm using for my projection.  See here - thank you!  -->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788135/distortion-with-pixel-accurate-opengl-rendering-of-sprites